# Runtime customizable settings

Tags: r

I am coming from python and search for a pendant to a runtime customisable setting.

In a python package I would just have a
`package.settings` dictionary
and could change those settings with a simple:
`package.settings[key] = value`.

I tried to simulate dictionaries in R with a named list (I am aware of the hash package).
If I import the package, and want to change the list with:

```
package::settings$key = value
```

I get the error:

```
Error in package::settings <- value : object 'package' not found
```

How can I implement runtime customisable settings in R?
I know that I sometimes have to change my mental model (especially when switching languages ;), so if a dictionary is not the correct data structure, I am happy to hear it.

Comment: Values of variables in packages are generally locked so you cannot change them from outside the package. In R, if packages have options/settings, you might share those settings via the `options()` command which globally tracks preferences.

Comment: I stumbled over it, but don't like it because it is in the global namespace. Is there really no alternative that allows to store the package settings in the namespace of the package? In perhaps 80% of the cases they won't be changed.

Comment: You'd just have to track a private object in your package and then write functions that will update that object on the user's behalf. User's wouldn't be able to update the object directly (at least not easily) because they can't modify the package's environment, but a function from the package can do so.

Comment: The ggplot [theme_set()](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/a27c365b688b56540e0fea4863219a35fd5a502b/R/theme-current.R) function does things in that sort of way if you want a reference.

Comment: So good old ugly getters and setters. :( Thank you very much for your help! If you write it in an answer I will accept it.